# SQL Server : Insert data from Linked Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL Servers: `Server1` and `Server2`. The servers are linked and the user linking the two servers is db_owner.

When I am at `Server1` and write the following:

```
  INSERT INTO Server2.dbname.dbo.ContractPermission (ContractNo, UsrCode, Extra)
  VALUES  ('29977', 'xxx', 1)
```

it works like a charm!

But when I am at `Server1` and write this:

```
INSERT INTO Server2.dbname.dbo.ContractPermission
   SELECT 
       [ContractNo]
       ,'xxx'
       ,[Extra]
   FROM 
       Server2.dbname.dbo.ContractPermission
   WHERE 
       UsrCode = 'yyy'
```

it does NOT work. The error code returned is:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

The funny thing is that if I connect to Server2 and use the exact same code it works!

So my confusion is: Why does this not work form Server1 when I have proven that I can INSERT elements in the table from Server1. And I have also proven that the SQL works when I am on Server2.

There is a slight difference in the SQL Server versions:

- Server1 is SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5532.0 (X64)
- Server2 is SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)

It is not a big problem as I can always execute it from Server2. I am just curious why it doesn't work from `Server1`.

Comment: Most likely, your `ContractPermission` table has more than just those three columns that you provide data for in your `SELECT` in the second example. That's why you should **always** explicitly define the **list of columns** in your `INSERT` statements

Comment: Yes, you are right! And t-clausen.dk below is right as well.
But still strange that it works when executed directly on Server2 then!
The only extra column in the table is an Id field with is having its Identity Specification set to Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the columns you had in your first example.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Server2.dbname.dbo.ContractPermission
  (ContractNo, UsrCode, Extra )
SELECT 
  [ContractNo]
  ,'xxx'
  ,[Extra]
FROM Server2.dbname.dbo.ContractPermission
WHERE UsrCode = 'yyy'
```